# Как получить точное время в php?

Tags: php

Например, иногда в месяце бывает 30 или 31 день. И такой код не сработает:

```
<?php
*****

$months = round(date('n', $time_difference));

*****
?>
```

Код

```
<?php
function timestamp($session_time) {
    $time_difference = time() - $session_time ;
    $seconds = $time_difference ;
    $minutes = round($time_difference / 60 );
    $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 );
    $days = round($time_difference / 86400 );
    $weeks = round($time_difference / 604800 );
    $months = round($time_difference / 2419200 );
    $years = round($time_difference / 29030400 );
}
$session_time ="1444753035";
//$session_time=time();
echo timestamp($session_time);
?>
```

Как получить точное время в `php`?

Comment: а готовая функция `date()` не помогла?

Comment: @Saidolim Мне нужно расчет сколько день в этом месяцу и сколько день в этом году и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В PHP есть встроенные методы для работы с датами. См. [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a дней');
```

Comment: Спасибо вам !!!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php
мануал по работе с серверами точного времени.

так же в недрах гугла нашел скрипт-пример:

```
function sinctimestamp($host)
{
$f=fsockopen ($host,13);
$s='';
while (!feof($f)){
$s.=fgets ($f);
}
$s=strtotime($s);
return $s;
}
 echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", sinctimestamp('main.ntp.kiev.ua'));
```

http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/NTPPoolServers
ссылка на ntp сервера с точным временем

и еще один интересный мануал: https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/time-synchronization-with-ntp-server-in-php.html

либо второй вариант: высчитывать время на сервере на основе mktime() для твоей часовой зоны. Когда у меня была подобная задача, то я именно так ее и решал. Если нужно могу набросать пример кода.

Comment: Мне нужно расчет сколько день в этом месяцу и сколько день в этом году и т. д.

Comment: т.е. задача не в генерации точного времени на ходу, а в том чтобы сформировать таблицу в стиле:



Год | Дни месяца  |  Месяц |  Дни
2015  |  30  |  Июнь  | 366
2015  |  31  |  Август  |  366
2015 | 30 | Сентябрь | 366
2015 | 31 | Октябрь | 366



или в чем суть задачи?

Comment: И проблема в генерации как можно генерировать?